# Anyway to configure a health check in Azure to ensure a file share is mounted or not?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, azure-files

Basically for an application, we're planning to mount a Azure fileshare to directly write the logs to. However we want to create a health check to notify the team if the fileshare mount fails. Can someone help me how I can implement this functionality? Its a RHEL VM in Azure

Answer (score 1):

•   Yes, there is a way through which you can check whether the Azure file share has been mounted successfully or not in the Linux VM or not. You can run a script in your Linux VM through custom script extension and check its output whether the azure file share has mounted successfully or not.

Run the script in the below github link named ‘AzFileDiagnostics.sh’ in your RHEL Linux VM through the commands as below: -

Github link : - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-files-samples/tree/master/AzFileDiagnostics/Linux

Commands for the script to run: - ‘sudo bash AzFileDiagnostics.sh’ or ‘sudo bash AzFileDiagnostics.sh -u //storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/sharename’

Output: -

[image: Linux Azure File share diagnostics]

•   This script when run will check all the prerequisites for connecting to Azure File share like checking port 445 TCP, SMB 3.3 for encryption purposes, cifs-utils package is installed or not, etc., and when all these requirements are met, it will mount the azure file share through the commands as stated above. Also, you can check the diagnostics logs through monitoring section by enabling them and collecting logs regarding this script for connection details.

Please find the below link for more reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems#solution